# I have put an wp specific extension in my extension directory but it does not appear in the manager

Tags: extension

I have uploaded and extracted the CIVIEVENT WIDGET to www/www/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext hit refresh on the CiviCRM Extensions administer page but the extension does not appear.  Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: Just to be thorough: you've set your extensions directory in the system settings?

Comment: It is set to: [civicrm.files]/ext/ and: [civicrm.files] /home/california/www/www/wp-content/uploads/civicrm

Comment: Did you hit the "refresh" button on your "manage extensions" screen in Civi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this a WordPress extension (even though I found it on the CiviCRM extension page) and on about page 3 of the readme.txt it tells you to install it into the WordPress extensions directory.